# Gridview. getcellvalue - is there any restrictions in the rows analyzed

Tags: vba

I have the report in SAP.
Macro is taking the name of the document from the report (one of the column - for example 5), goes to the invoice and saving it.
I used this code to get the document name

```
Dim rows_sap As Integer
rows_sap = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").RowCount - 2
```

The above checks how many rows there is in the report

```
Dim myArray() As Variant
ReDim Preserve myArray(rows_sap - 1, 1)
 
Dim jj As Double
For jj = 0 To rows_sap - 1
Dim pdf_name As String
Set gridview = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell")
pdf_name = gridview.getcellvalue(jj, "REFBN")
myArray(jj, 1) = pdf_name
'MsgBox (myArray(jj, 1))
Next jj
```

The above code takes the document name to the virtual table.

This macro works well, but not for the report where there is more than `67` lines. On the line `68` macro gives following error

[image]

When I used `MsgBox` for the line `68` I received

[image]

For 2 different orders I have the same `0000000069` order name, where in both cases there was no such document name.

Also checked the last row from `myArray`. It was empty.

Is it possible, that `gridview.getcellvalue` takes only `67` lines? Have anyone seen this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.

The problem here was the moving the bar after 67 line.
This code solved the problem

Dim jj As Double
For jj = 0 To rows_sap - 1
Dim pdf_name As String
If jj = 30 Then
If rows_sap > 58 Then
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").firstVisibleRow = 58
Else
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").firstVisibleRow = rows_sap
End If
End If

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
Dim rows_sap As Integer
rows_sap = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell").RowCount '- 2

Dim myArray() As Variant
ReDim Preserve myArray(rows_sap - 1, 1)

Dim jj As Double
Dim pdf_name As String
Set gridview = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell")
For jj = 0 To rows_sap - 1
 gridview.setCurrentCell jj, "REFBN" 
 pdf_name = gridview.getcellvalue(jj, "REFBN")
 myArray(jj, 1) = pdf_name
 'MsgBox (myArray(jj, 1))
Next jj
```

Regards, ScriptMan